# How to Use Windows Services with Mongodb on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c#, mongodb, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I want to deploy my C# codes on Raspberry Pi 2. Raspberry Pi 2 wants Universal App but the MongoDb C# driver doesn't support Universal App.

Is there any way to run my code on Raspberry Pi? 
Is anyone using MongoDb and Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Anyone find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to expose your MongoDB data through a web service.

Comment: Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Sorry for late. Yes it's an another way but i just run raspi, if i create a webservice not comfortable for me. Thanks a lot.